# Converting Unicode string containing bytes to actual bytes

Tags: python, encoding

I have some gziped data but they lack the gzip header, I'm adding it manually.

```
gzip_header = u'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
gzip_body = u'\x95\x93\xdfn\xe3D\x18\xc5q\xebv\xb3\xb4\xbb\x80\xb4H+\x84P\x05W,$\xf....'

gzip_content = gzip_header + gzip_body
unziped = .... ?

print unziped
```

What's the correct way to unzip `gzip_content` ?

Comment: Why are you using Unicode? You have a byte stream, use `bytes`: `gzip_header = b'...'` and `gzip_body = b'...'`. Then look at the `gzip` module.

Comment: why don't use save it in file and use `gzip` tool or module to ungzip. You could also use `io.ByteIO` to create fake file in memory and ungzip it.

Comment: I can't save it in a file, I'm using Unicode because i receive the gzip_body as a unicode string. However, I can change it to b ?

Comment: I created gzip file, read it to memory (`gzip_content = open('test.gz', 'rb').read()`) and then I can decopress it in memory - `import gzip ; print( gzip.decompress(gzip_content) )`